# App hang when I try add new object to PFRelation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to add one more object to PFRelation. I think I've check most common issue and object which I'm trying to add is already saved at parse. Also, relation is pointing to the same type of class in parse as type of object which I'm trying to add.

**Code**

```
func tapToJoin() {
    dispatch_async(queue) { () -> Void in
        if let user = User.localUsername() {
            joinToEvent(user, toEventWithId: eventId) { (success) in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    if success {
                        SVProgressHUD.showSuccessWithStatus("Joined")
                    } else {
                        SVProgressHUD.showErrorWithStatus("Error")
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

func joinToEvent(user:User,toEventWithId eventId:String, complete:(Bool)->Void){
    do {
        //1. query event
        let eventQuery = PFQuery(className: "Event", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "objectId = %@",eventId))
        let event = try eventQuery.findObjects().first
        //2. find user
        let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "objectId = %@",user.id))
        let parseUser = try userQuery.findObjects().first!
        //3. add user to event.participants
        let eventParticipants = event?.objectForKey("participants") as! PFRelation
        eventParticipants.addObject(parseUser)
        //4. save event to parse
        try event?.save()
        complete(true)
    } catch {
        complete(false)
    }
}
```

**Problem**

App hang at `eventParticipants.addObject(parseUser)`. I'm not sure how I should approach this issue.

Comment: At least one problem is that eventParticipants should be initialized with `event.relationForKey`, not `objectForKey`

Comment: -.- I don't know how I miss it. Please add it as answer so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one problem is that eventParticipants should be initialized with `event.relationForKey`, not `objectForKey`